# ERROR: Additional information: Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm having this issue with a program that adds files to my combobox and also added to database.

I had 2 button add+ and - to delete the fields one by one on combobox

when i click ADD + button the data in my orm that means i have another combobox, lable,datetimepicker these are added in my FAVORITES combobox

```
combofavorite.Items.Add("Report Type: " + cmbreporttype.Text + " Date From: " + dateTimePicker1.Text + " To: " + dateTimePicker2.Text);
            combofavorite.SelectedIndex = 0;
            MessageBox.Show("Add Report Type: " + cmbreporttype.Text + " Date From: " + dateTimePicker1.Text + " To: " + dateTimePicker2.Text + " TO Favorite", "Added to Favorite", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Add the added data in the combobox is also added into database table

```
 MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyCon);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO favorite (favorite) VALUES (@favo)", connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@favo", combofavorite.Text);
            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();



 private void cmbfav_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ID = cmbfav.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }
```

When i try this i got an error on here.

[image]

Plese help me to solve my problem .

Comment: Well, don't set DataSource, populate the Items collection manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Anu Dont use `combofavorite.Text` in AddWithValue.

instead of this

```
     MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO favorite (favorite) VALUES (@favo)", connection);
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@favo", combofavorite.Text);
```

use this:

```
      MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO favorite (favorite) VALUES (@favo)", connection);
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@favo","Report Type: " + cmbreporttype.Text + " Date From: " + dateTimePicker1.Text + " To: " + dateTimePicker2.Text);
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: thanks i try your code . please tell me how to fetch the data from database to combobox please refer me some link.

Comment: http://www.thedevelopertips.com/DotNet/WindowsFormsCSharp/Fill-combobox-items-from-Database-windowsforms.aspx?id=8

Comment: see this link it helps you.